# Django filter: dynamic slice

Tags: django

I am refering to this slice filter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice

if I have this list `a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, is there any way to take the first half of this list?
Something like `{{ a|slice:":3" }}`.

But instead of `3` I want the size of list `a`. And `a` can have even or odd number of elements. And I don't want to pass the list length as a variable in the context from the view

**later EDIT**

I was wondering if there is another solution, other than a custom filter

Answer (score 2):

If used in a for-loop, you can do this:

```
{% for item in a %}
  {% if forloop.counter < forloop.revcounter %}
    {# first half of list #}
  {% else %}
    {# second half of list #}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: smart move...yet, I think it is more ellegant to use a custom filter so far

Answer (score 0):

You can do custom filter for this purpose:

```
@register.filter("half_slice")
def half_slice_filter(value):
    return value[:len(value)/2]
```

Comment: oh yes, forgot to mention. I already did a custom filter. I was interested in another solution if it is possible. I want to take both the first half and the second half of a list.